# How can I vaildate radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

How i put validation on check box?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function Validate(){
   var cntct = document.getElementById("contact").value;
   if (cntct.value=="")
   {
      alert("Please select contact medium");
      return false;
   }
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="SMS">
<label>SMS</label> <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="CALL">
<label>CALL</label> <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="EMAIL">
<label>EMAIL</label>
```

please help..

Comment: Your multiple `id` attributes are invalid - it must be unique. You will need to iterate over all inputs with the same name and search for the `.checked` one.

Comment: Huh? This example shows radio buttons. The property of radio-buttons is that one of them needs to be selected at all times. While the browser wont set one arbitrarily, you can't unselect one once it's done. Simple answer - no need to validate radio buttons! Just set one of them to checked in the html. Add the word 'checked' between type="radio" and name="contact" _for the first radio button only_ . Also, as mentioned, you can't duplicate IDs like you have. give them unique ones - e.g id='smsRb' id='callRb' id='emailRb'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of checkboxes and radiobuttons, the element is checked when the "checked" property is true:

```
function Validate(){
    var selectedValue = "";
    var cntct = document.getElementsByname("contact");
    for(var i=0;i<cntct.length;i++) {
        if (cntct[i].checked)
        {
            selectedValue = cntct.value;
        }
    }
    if(selectedValue == "") {
        alert("Please select contact medium");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that you have multiple elements with the same ID. This is not allowed, in such case the browser will return only the last element with that ID. You need to iterate over the elements with the same `name` and pick one with attribute `checked`. See the code above

Comment: The checked attribute is boolean and doesn't necessarily indicate that the checkbox is actually checked. If the checkbox doesn't have the checked attribute, it will return `null` whether the checkbox is checked or not. Far better to test the checked property: `if (cntct.checked)`.

Comment: your code have a problem when i select a radio button it again and click submit button it again open an alert box. After 2 or 3 times it submit the form please help

Comment: @ZainAbid just add return true or false statements to appropriate places, see updated code

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
if(cntct == "")
{

}

The cntct variable is the value!

Answer (score 0):

> How i put validation on check box?

I presume you mean "how do I make sure one of the radio buttons is checked when the form is submitted" (supposing there is a form you haven't shown).

The simple way is to make one checkbox selected by default, then you know that one will always be selected and you don't have to check, e.g.

```
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="CALL" checked>
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="EMAIL">
```

The other way is to loop over the radio buttons when the form is submitted (or whatever event you decide to base the validation on) and make sure one is checked. e.g.

```
function checkButton() {
  var nodes = document.getElementsByName('contact');
  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // If find a checked one, job's done
    if (nodes[i].checked) return true;
  }

  // Otherwise, none were checked
  return false;
}
```

There is an input type text with a name of contact, but it won't have a checked property so will be treated like an unchecked radio.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>
function SubmitIt()
{
    if (document.forms.myform.elements.contact.value == "") 
    {
        alert("Please select contact medium..."); 
    }
}
</script>

<form name="myform" id="myform">
   <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="SMS">
   <label>SMS</label> <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="CALL">
   <label>CALL</label> <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="EMAIL">
   <label>EMAIL</label>

   <button onclick="SubmitIt();">Submit</button>
</form>
```